# update en c# con base sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, update

estoy intentando hacer un update pero por alguna razón solo recarga la pagina y no hace nada, no marca ni un error ni nada

este es mi metodo que llena mi BO con los campos

```
 public void llenarweb()
        {
            Web_BO.C_Titulo = txt_car_titulo1.Text;
            Web_BO.C_Contenido = txt_car_contenido1.Text;
            Web_BO.S1_Titulo = txt_s1_titulo.Text;
            Web_BO.S1_Contenido1 = txt_s1_contenido.Text;
            Web_BO.S2_Titulo = txt_s2_titulo.Text;
            Web_BO.S2_Contenido1 = txt_s2_contenidio1.Text;
            Web_BO.S2_Contenido2 = txt_s2_contenido2.Text;
            Web_BO.S2_Contenido3 = txt_s2_contenido3.Text;
            Web_BO.id_web = 1;

        }
```

y con este boton deberia hacer el update pero como repito no lo realiza

```
protected void btn_probar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llenarweb();
        web_DAO.ActualizarPruebaWebSIIE(Web_BO);

    }
```

el metodo contiene esto

```
public int ActualizarPruebaWebSIIE(Web_BO obj_web)
{

    
    string sen = "Update Prueba_WebSIIE  set Prueba_C_Titulo ='" + obj_web.C_Titulo + "',  Prueba_C_Contenido = '"+ obj_web.C_Contenido + 
        "' ,  Prueba_S1_Titulo = '"+ obj_web.S1_Titulo + "' , Prueba_S1_Contenido1 = '"+ obj_web.S1_Contenido1 + "' , Prueba_S2_Titulo = '"+ obj_web.S2_Titulo +
        "' ,  Prueba_S2_Contenido1 = '"+ obj_web.S2_Contenido1 + "' , Prueba_S2_Contenido2 = '"+obj_web.S2_Contenido2+ "' ,   Prueba_S2_Contenido3 = '" 
        + obj_web.S2_Contenido3 + "'  where id_web = '" + obj_web.id_web + "'";

   

    int id = conex.EjecutarComando(sen);

    return id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que `obj_web.id_web` no se encuentre registrada por lo tanto no lo encuentra para ser actualizado o simplemente no trae valor.
Aplica `try catch` cuando se realiza la operacion de base de datos esto en tu metodo `EjecutarComando` para controlar los posibles fallos en tu conexion y operaciones de la base.

Ejemplo `try catch`

```
try {
  int id = conex.EjecutarComando(sen);
  return id;
}catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            return 0;
        }
```